# this2.props.addToList is undefined, List creation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, react-native, variables

Diet.js

```
export class Diet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
this.state = {
      list: [],
    };
    this.addToList = this.addToList.bind(this);
  }

addToList(item) {
    const list = [...this.state.list, item];
    this.setState({ list });
  }
 render() {

<FoodCreate addToList={this.addToList} />

return (

<FoodList items={this.state.list} />

)}
```

FoodCreate

```
export class FoodCreate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      FoodName: "",
      calories: 0,
    };
  }

render() {

    return (
<Button transparent>
          <Icon
            name="checkmark"
            style={{ fontSize: 25, color: "red" }}
            onPress={() => this.props.addToList(FoodName, calories)}
          />
        </Button>
<TextInput
            placeholder="Food Name"
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            style={styles.inptFood}
            value={FoodName}
            onChangeText={(FoodName) => this.setState({ FoodName: FoodName })}
          />
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Calories"
              placeholderTextColor="white"
              style={styles.inptMacros}
              keyboardType="numeric"
              value={calories}
              maxLength={5}
              onChangeText={(calories) => this.setState({ calories: calories })}
            />
```

FoodList

```
export class FoodList extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Content>
        <List>
          <ListItem itemDivider>
            <Text>Food</Text>
            {this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <ListItem key={index}>
                  <Text>{item.FoodName}</Text>
                  <Text>{item.calories}</Text>
                </ListItem>
              );
            })}
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Content>
    );
  }
}

export default FoodList;
```

Hi, I'm new to programming and React Native, so I'm trying to create a Grocery List by letting the user type `FoodName` and `Calories` and pressing the Icon: Check in `FoodCreate` page, and List it in the `FoodList` page, at the moment when I run the code gives me back an error: `_this2.props.addToList is not a function`, I've tried many solutions but I'm not sure where the error is.

Comment: Your code isn't valid, it's confusing (does `addToList` take 1 argument or 2?), and you haven't created an example that can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
class FoodCreate extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button title="aaa" onPress={() => this.props.addToList('name')}></Button>
    );
  }
}

export default class Diet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [],
    };
    this.addToList = this.addToList.bind(this);
  }

  addToList(item) {
    const list = [...this.state.list, item];
    this.setState({list});
  }
  render() {
    return <FoodCreate addToList={this.addToList} />;
  }
}
```

I use the above code and didn't get the error

But I think you can have a better code
Don't use `this.addToList = this.addToList.bind(this);`, you can convert `addToList` to arrow function and remove this line

```
addToList = item => {
    const list = [...this.state.list, item];
    this.setState({list});
  };
```